# Inline Handlebars CSS not working

Tags: html, css, handlebars.js

So i have my handlebars template

```
<ul>
{{#each familia}}
    <li class="listItem">
        <div class="items" style="background-image:url(img/{{attributes.imagen}}">
            <div class="info">
                <h3>{{attributes.nombre}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

when compiles it puts the url well, but the background-image not shows the image, plus in the chrome console it makes me a invalid property value... what am i doing wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your CSS, `url` needs a closing parenthesis:

```
background-image:url(img/{{attributes.imagen}})
// this was missing --------------------------^
```

The structure should work fine otherwise: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/zWp3d/

Comment: And @mu-is-too-short - you have a typo for the word typo ("type")...so meta.

Comment: @jbyrd Maybe that was an intentional joke. Or maybe not.